# NullReference issue in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a reference to two of my game objects in Unity which are "ScoreEntryContainer" and its child "template":

[image: screenshot]

In my script, I've added two public transform variables to get a reference to these. However, Unity throws a `NullReferenceException` pointing to the reference to the "Template".

[image: Error]

Template is a container that has three Text UI game objects.

In the inspector, I have assigned these game objects to the script component as well. The error is pointing to the Debug.Log line in the code below:

```
public class ScoreboardScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform container;
    public Transform template;


    private List<ScoreEntry> scoreEntryList;
    private List<Transform> scoreEntryTransformList;

    public void Awake()
    {
        template.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        scoreEntryList = new List<ScoreEntry>()
        {
            new ScoreEntry(10,150f),
            new ScoreEntry(20,150f),
            new ScoreEntry(30,150f)

        };


        foreach(ScoreEntry sc in scoreEntryList)
        {
            float templateHeight = 25f;

            Transform entry = Instantiate(template, container);
            RectTransform entryRectTransform = entry.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            entryRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, -templateHeight * scoreEntryList.IndexOf(sc));
            entry.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            int rank = 0;

            //entry.Find("SerialNoText").GetComponent<Text>().text = rank.ToString(); 

            Debug.Log(entry.Find("SerialNoText").GetComponent<Text>().text); // Error here
            float time = sc.time;
            int minutes = (int)(time / 60);
            int seconds = (int)(time % 60);
            //entry.Find("TimeText").GetComponent<Text>().text = minutes.ToString() + ":" + seconds.ToString();

        }

    }
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

See inspector:

[image: here].

`entry` is a reference to the `Template` GameObject.

See `Template` in inspector:

[image: Template]

Comment: Please see [tag:visual-studio] for information on when to use that tag. This question is not an appropriate place for that tag.

Comment: entry is supposed to gain a reference to Template. See edit for screenshot.

Comment: Can you tell us what line is line 41 in ScoreboardScript.cs is (per error message)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've figured it out.

The problem was because I used TextMeshPro instead of Text in the UI which threw the null exception. So I changed it accordingly in the script.

Answer (score 0):

`Template` doesn't have a `Text` component on it. So, calling `entry.Find("SerialNoText").GetComponent<Text>()` returns a null reference.

Comment: It still gave me the same error. Not sure what you mean by not having a child. I've named the game object as "SerialNoText" like how I've named every other game object.

Comment: I think the problem is that when the template is being instantiated, its child objects aren't being instantiated.

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva I changed the answer using the new information in the comments and answer.

Comment: @Ruzihm doesn't Unity even through a more specific error? Afaik something like `You are trying to get Component XY, but GameObject has no such component`

Comment: @derHugo As far as I can recall, a valid way of checking if a gameobject has a component is to use `GetComponent` and check if the result is null. I don't think it throws an error then.

Comment: @Ruzihm oh true that ... somehow I remember having seen such a message in the console though ^^